# How to return own object?

Tags: php

I have 2 classes `TestHeaders`and `TestHeader`.

Function `TestHeaders->profile()` returns `new TestHeader()` object.

`TestHeader` class has 2 arguments. First is object `TestHeaders`. So my problem is that in `TestHeaders->profile()` I have code like this:

```
return new TestHeader(new TestHeader(), 'profile.php');
```

I can't create `new TestHeader()` but class `TestHeader` can't modify. Someone could help me how can I do that ?

```
class TestHeaders
{
    public function profile(int $userId): TestHeader
    {
        return new TestHeader(new TestHeaders(), 'profile.php');
    }
}
```

```
class TestHeader
{
    private TestHeaders $headers;

    public function __construct(TestHeaders $headers, public string $url)
    {
        $this->headers = $headers;
    }

    public function send(): void
    {
        $this->headers->setHeader("Location: $this->url");
    }

}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your design (or the way you are using it) if they are linked like this.

Comment: Your current code seems to be creating an infinite loop of one class calling another class. Whatever you're doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Your problem is a circular reference. What is the purpose of that strange usage?